# Publicar App.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy tratando de publicar mi aplicación en IIS, pero no ha sido posible. He intentado múltiples soluciones, leído documentación y muchas cosas más. Al momento de ejecutar el sitio desde IIS obtengo el error 500. Alguien podría ayudarme a indicarme si este es un problema en mi aplicacion o propiamente de la configuración que se realiza al publicar la app desde visual.

Deberia de colocar algo antes de publicar en este apartado?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y como configuraste el servidor para levantar el proyecto publicado? ¿Usas puertos?

Comment: ¿Algún log de parte del server?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo he creado una app de prueba la he publicado en el servidor y si me funciona sin problemas. Es lo que no me explico. Mi pregunta es tambien si deberia de modificar algo o estoy haciendo mal la publicacion del sitio en la carpeta que deseo

Comment: @fredyfx que debería de poder encontrar en el log? Estoy revisándolo pero no veo algo que diga error

Comment: EventViewer en el Windows Server (?)

Comment: Estas publicando local o en azure?

Comment: @fredyfx no veo nada de ello en el log

Comment: @gbianchi localmente en mi servidor